# Is it possible to add descriptive comments to Dynamic Content

Tags: azure-data-factory

When writing complex expressions as **Dynamic Content**, is there a way to add descriptive inline comments to the expression?

These symbols don't work; --, //, /* */

Comment: Could you please add any sample data and expected result?

Comment: I want to add comments (text after --) to the code. But it's erroring out.

-- Explain the purpose
@if(  or(or(equals(item().target_table, 'table1'),equals(item().target_table, 'table2')),or(equals(item().target_table, 'table3'),equals(item().target_table, 'table4')))
  , 'A'  -- Explanation of logic A
  ,if(and(or(equals(item().target_table, 'table5'),equals(item().target_table, 'table6'))
  , equals(activity('Lookup1').output.firstrow.Data_Filter1, 'ExpectedValue')) 
    ,'B' -- Explanation of logic B
  ,'C')-- Everything else
  )

Answer (score 1):

You can add comments to data flow expressions, but not in pipeline expressions